# Querying for records on a date with an offset from a given date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Consider I have a date as 29/03/2011.
 I want to query records for one day, 5 day  and 10 day post this date.

Say, the sample fields are F1,F2,F3;

My code goes like this

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 FROM T1 WHERE T1.Date = ...
```

I am using MS Access 2007, and I am not able to understand how to query for a date which is having an offset.

I have tinkered and experimented with DateAdd() but is giving me an error. 
Would like to have a solution.

Soham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, you can use:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.Date >= #2011-07-11# + 10
```

To show all records which are 10 days and afterwards a certain date.

or this to show all records with are exactly 10 days from a certain date:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.Date = #2011-07-11# + 10
```

---

There is a huge problem though, if your dates have a time part! The above will not catch records where `date = #2011-07-11 11:43#`. It will match only records having time part `00:00:00`. So it's equivalent to having:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.Date = #2011-07-21 00:00:00#
```

Which is probably not what you want. It's preferable to use this:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM T1 
WHERE DateValue(T1.Date) = #2011-07-11# + 10
```

or this, **which can use an index on the `Date` field, so it's the best approach:**

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.Date >= #2011-07-11# + 10
  AND T1.Date <  #2011-07-11# + 11
```

Comment: Though I didnt need the record of dates starting after 10 days, but this solution solves the problem perfectly. Many thanks

Comment: @Soham: See my edit for a detail which may give you errors later and is hard to catch.

Comment: The last one is better because it will use the indexes.